# Request Module with Cloudflare API returns 'invalid content type'

Tags: node.js, cloudflare

So, I was using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to connect to the Cloudflare API. I was trying to add a DNS record.

`api.js`:

```
var request = require('request');
var content = 'dnslink=/' + mode + '/' + cid
var headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
   'X-Auth-Email': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'X-Auth-Key': process.env.KEY
};

var dataString = '{"type":"TXT","name":'+ random + '".r.getipfs.xyz","content":' + content + '"ttl":3600,"priority":10,"proxied":true}'

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/dns_records',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
console.log(body)
}
request(options, callback);
}
module.exports = {add}
```

Then when I called it using the function, it gave me this error:

`{"result":null,"success":false,"errors":[{"code":9207,"message":"Failed to parse request body, content-type must be application/json"}],"messages":[]}`

I honestly don't know what's going on. I was referencing to this guide Cloudflare published: [This one (Jumps straight to the point](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-create-dns-record) Which seemed fine when I used cURL to try it out, but it wont work with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?